# open new Thread inside for statement bu wait until my Thread will finish before open new one

Tags: c#, winforms

i try to my operation inside for statement in different Thread but i want to wait until my Tread will finish before open new Thread:

```
public class Play
{
    private string _filePath;
    private int _deviceNumber;

    public Play(string filePath, int deviceNumber)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
        _deviceNumber = deviceNumber;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(send);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void send()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\SendQueue\SendQueue\bin\Debug\Send.exe");
        processStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {2}{1}{2}", (_deviceNumber).ToString(), _filePath, "\"");
        processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

from start button click i am play all the file within my Listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox.Items.Count && shouldContinue; i++)
{
    PlayFile play = new PlayFile ((string)ListBox.Items[i], add);
    playCapture.start();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to wait for one thread to finish before starting another one, why not just do everything on one thread?

Comment: cause i don't my GUI will stuck until my process will finish (could run few minutes)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're creating threads here anyway, if you're just using them to launch a new process and wait for it to exit - you may as well just launch the process and (if needed) wait for it to finish rather than waiting for the blocked thread.

Comment: My point is that you could start *one* new thread, then do everything on that. Just create a queue of items to process.

Comment: can i have an example how to do it ?

Comment: @user1269592 If you Wait on the thread then you'll block the UI thread, and it's just as bad as doing whatever right in the UI thread.  You need to do something else in the background thread and let the UI thread go back to idling so it can handle UI events.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => send());
    taskA.Wait();
```

But this will block the caller thread of the task (The work will be done in a second thread but actually, the caller thread will be blocked during the execution) you will not benefit from doing the work in another thread!

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610.aspx) will help you

If you need to do all of the work in another thread, and keep the main stream going without block, you can put your `for` statement in a thread, this will work perfectly.